# "Batteries included" version of Languagetool local server?

Tags: software-installation, spell-checking

Is there a simple-to-install version of Languagetool that I can use to run a local server for LanguageTool? I would like to use the various add-ons based on it (VS Code, Thunderbird, etc.) offline and without sending data over the internet.

Ideally I'd like to add a PPA, run `apt install languagetool-server` and have everything working out of the box. I have seen that there is a Snap version, but (1) it does not come with features such as n-grams, and (2) it only runs the server while the GUI interface is running.

There are installation instructions in German [here](https://gnulinux.ch/languagetool-selber-hosten), which are very detailed and include running it as a systemd service from an unprivileged user account. However I'd prefer something that is maintained and autoupdates to new versions. (Yes, I know I am lazy.)